# Flyway Init Order

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I've got a Java Spring Boot application, with Flyway configured as a dependency in my Maven pom.xml (I have a parent pom and a project pom... Flyway is defined in my project pom).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

and just a couple of entries in application.properties:

```
flyway.enabled=true
flyway.out-of-order=true
```

I can run a maven task to get Flyway to run `migrate` to create/update my database and then run my application against that, but I'm having trouble getting it to call `migrate` at the right time just by running my application (which is obviously important in prod). It looks like all of my Spring classes are being instantiated first, some of which involves looking at the database, and then Flyway migration happens after, so for instance if you run the application against an empty database the application crashes when trying to access anything in the database.

Any tips on where to look to see where I'm going wrong to get Flyway to do its migration earlier in the start-up process of my Spring Boot application?

Comment: In your parent pom, is Flyway dependency present. We use gradle and flyway appears right at the top.

Comment: Just to be clear, I've got it defined in my project pom, not my parent pom, but to your question, while it is listed first, I do not have any specific dependencies indicated. Maybe I should look into that - otherwise it may also be that I have to declare it as a configured Bean directly in the code and indicate dependencies there. But either way, I'm not sure what dependency to indicate directly on Flyway, since a dependency indicates what must be configured _before_. So maybe I have to indicate Flyway as a dependency on something else that is currently being loaded early on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data source configuration looks like, but you could declare your JPA config in such a way that makes it dependent on the flyway migration.

You could declare a `@DependsOn("flyway")` annotation on whatever `@Config` class or datasource bean, "flyway" being the declared name of your flyway configuration bean. Then, on your flyway configuration bean, qualify the bean annotation with an initMethod property like the following: `@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try change "flyway.out-of-order=false"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try using event listners like ApplicationStartedEvent.

```
 @EventListener
  public void migrate(ApplicationStartedEvent applicationStartedEvent) {
           //do some checks
           flyway.migrate();
  }
```